# Audio stops working after running shell script

Tags: audio, audio-playback

This is my first question on this site, so please excuse (and point out) any mistakes I make in my post.

I'm running Bookworm on a Rpi4.

I need audio for a project that I'm doing, so I decided to use the Rpi HiFi AMP Hat made by InnoMaker (https://www.inno-maker.com/product/hifi-amp-hat/). My project is controlled by a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

voice=$(python3 voice.py)
face=$(python3 face.py)
finger=$(python3 finger.py)

cd assets
echo $voice > nameTemp.txt
cd ..

if [[ "$voice" != "None" ]]; then
    python3 open.py
else
    python3 deny.py
fi
```

The first time I run this script, it runs perfectly. However, if I try to run it again, no audio plays. What's really weird is that I can play audio multiple times just fine by clicking on audio files, but when I run this shell script, it stops working after the first time. After running the script, no audio plays from the Pi (including clicking on files, etc.). If I run the python scripts individually, nothing goes wrong, the issue only occurs when running the shell script.

I thought the problem was the DAC/amp, so I switched it out for Adafruit's Sound Bonnet, but that had the same problem.  I then thought maybe there is an issue with what I did in my /boot/config.txt file, but I don't know what could be the issue. The only lines I modified are:

```
dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=audio=on
dtoverlay=hifiberry-amp
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,noaudio
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is causing this problem? Please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: What does your python code do? Personally I would have one Python program handling everything rather than shell scripts.

Comment: You need to ***start*** by contacting your "HAT" vendor for troubleshooting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I listened to @CoderMike's advice and used Python rather than a shell script. From there, I was able to narrow down the problem to one script. I realized I made a stupid mistake and was using a GPIO pin that the DAC/amp was using to power a different device. Thanks for the advice and the help!